Handling Serializable type in Spring SOAP Client
I have to call a very old SOAP service from my Spring Boot application. I use the cxf-codegen-plugin to generate the java stubs at compile time using wsdl2java. Now, I have these elements that are marked of type Serializable in the service's WSDL. So I get an unmarshalling error when I get the response back
<xs:schema xmlns:ax27="http://io.java/xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://validation.common.services.scope.xxx.com/xsd">
<xs:import namespace="http://io.java/xsd"/>
<xs:complexType name="ValidationResult">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="all" nillable="true" type="ax25:ValidationMessage"/>
**<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value" nillable="true" type="ax27:Serializable"/>**
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ValidationMessage">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="code" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="error" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="info" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="objectId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="objectType" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="type" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="warning" type="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>


<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://io.java/xsd">
<xs:complexType name="Serializable">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

Here is the excerpt from pom.xml for the codegen plugin :
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                      <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                          <wsdlOptions>
                              <wsdlOption>
                                  <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/MyService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                  <wsdlLocation>classpath:MyService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                  <bindingFiles>
                                      <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/binding/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                                  </bindingFiles>
                                  <packagenames>
                                      <packagename>http://io.java/xsd=com.xxx.io.java.xsd</packagename>
                                      <packagename>http://rmi.java/xsd=com.xxx.rmi.java.xsd</packagename>
                                  </packagenames>
                              </wsdlOption>
                          </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

Bindings file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               jaxb:version="2.0">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" generateIsSetMethod="true" optionalProperty="primitive">
        <xjc:serializable uid="12343"/>

    </jaxb:globalBindings> </jaxb:bindings>

RESPONSE :
<ax25:all type="com.xxx.scope.services.common.validation.ValidationMessage">
      <ax25:code>6100161</ax25:code>
      <ax25:error>true</ax25:error>
      <ax25:info>false</ax25:info>
      <ax25:message>Quantity is required</ax25:message>
      <ax25:objectId/>
      <ax25:objectType/>
      <ax25:type>error</ax25:type>
      <ax25:warning>false</ax25:warning>
    </ax25:all>
    <ax25:value type="com.xxx.scope.cbo.data.asn.ASNKey">
      <ax21:aaaNumber>PR2406030009</ax21:aaaNumber>
      <ax21:businessUnit>88</ax21:businessUnit>
    </ax25:value>

Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: unexpected element (uri:"http://aaa.data.cbo.scope.xxx.com/xsd", local:"asnNumber"). Expected elements are (none)

Just a correction the actual error message recevied is =

Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: unexpected element (uri:"http://aaa.data.cbo.scope.xxx.com/xsd", local:"aaaNumber"). Expected elements are (none)
